# Android Studio - Compiling option

Tags: android, compilation, ide

I developed an android app with android studio selectiong the lowest androis os version. i tested the app on my samsung s4 and it works correctly, now i tested the same apk file on another device (LG g2) and when i open the app it close immediately. my app is very simple and i don't think to have used high version library, so i wanted to know if it was possible to compile my application for that specific device (LG g2) so that my app works on that phone (android 4.4.2). if not possible does someone know why that error?

this is manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tommaso.progetto">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace and relevant part of code...

Comment: i post an answer with manifest code

Comment: if you want to add information to your question,please use the "edit" option below your question. And we need to see the error log in your logcat console if something crashed...